# How to setup multi stores with different themes for Magento CE

Tags: theme, multistore

I'm new to Magento. Our plan of creating eCommerce website with Magento CE is like that: we only have one website (one domain), first, we will create one store, name 'handbag', the landing page will be all about handbags. In the near future, we will introduce electornical products and create the second store, name 'electronic'. When we introduce the second store, the landing page will be replaced with a new landing page which has icons to guide customers to select 'handbag' or 'electronic'. And the two stores will have its own theme. My questions are:
1. I know it is easy to create multiple stores, but no idea with how to create different themes for these two stores.
2. How to introduce a new landing page in Magento CE, with which, the users can select 'handbag' or 'electronic' stores, then the total different store theme will show up.

Thanks,
Collin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1. I know it is easy to create multiple stores, but no idea with how to create different themes for these two stores**

I hope that you have configure your theme for one store. now you have to change the color combination of different store. so you have to create new theme.

Suppose

```
app                              Skin
--design                         --design
  --Frontend                       --Frontend
    --default                        --default
      --store1theme                     --store1theme
```

Now you want to change only css then copy and paste the theme folder skin folder like below

```
app                              Skin
--design                         --design
  --Frontend                       --Frontend
    --default                        --default
      --store1theme                     --store1theme
                                        --store2theme
```

now go to your admin panel. `System >> Configuration >> Design`

Now you can see the "Current Configuration Scope" at starting of left menu. just click on that and select your store 1. Then it will redirect to the page. same as below

[image]

So this way you can set diff theme for diff store.

**2. How to introduce a new landing page in Magento CE,**

Its Simple create 2 cms page with same identifier and just the set diff store. Magento has functionality that it will call the pages as per store view automatically. just like below Image

[image]

Hope you got the proper Answer.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new website, store and view, you have to reindex

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

then you will be able to select a theme per every website you have.