# Magento Multisite using same theme for different websites but with the different style/css

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using a magento multisite setup. There i am having different websites and i want to use the same theme but with a different css/color customization for each one. I tried to create a new folder of style as per explained [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24367/how-to-setup-multi-stores-with-different-themes-for-magento-ce) . But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

Since 1.9.x you can add dependencies on **themes** and **packages**.

Add a `etc/theme.xml` and tell which parent you want to use.

```
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

This will add a dependency on the **rwd/default** theme.
That being said, brings me to a solution.

### Solution

Start creating a package per website, `website1` in `app/design/frontend/website1/default`

Add the `etc/theme.xml` (`app/design/frontend/website1/default/etc/theme.xml`) and set the parent to your base package like `rwd/default`. This way you can still use possibility to use *themes per package* per website.

Magento will lookup your file as

- app/design/frontend/website1/**theme**/template/file.phtml
- app/design/frontend/website1/**default**/template/file.phtml
- app/design/frontend/**rwd**/**default**/template/file.phtml
- app/design/frontend/**base**/**default**/template/file.phtml

The same goes for your images and css files

- skin/frontend/website1/**theme**/css/style.css
- skin/frontend/website1/**default**/css/style.css
- skin/frontend/**rwd**/**default**/css/style.css
- skin/frontend/**base**/**default**/css/style.css

You can do the same for website2, etcetera.

### Final tip

You can also keep your downloaded theme packages clean this way.
Download and install the package, create a custom package and add a dependency to the downloaded package. Put your changes in your custom package.

`app/design/frontend/custom/default/etc/theme.xml`

```
<theme>
    <parent>downloaded/default</parent>
</theme>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a master theme in `cms > design > package`.

Set *default* to your new *theme-name*
After that: Create a child-theme for each storeview and define it in

```
cms > design > themes > standard
```