# Product name is displayed on website as all caps, but was not entered in Admin as all caps

Tags: product

In the Admin Panel when I enter the following as the product name:

> Lighthouse Clear SF Stamp Mounts 160mm x 120mm  d (10 strips)

When I view the product on the website it displays as below (In uppercase):

> LIGHTHOUSE CLEAR SF STAMP MOUNTS 160MM X 120MM D (10 STRIPS)

I do not want it to make the change.  I want it just the way I typed it in Admin.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: My guess is that you have a CSS in your theme that is making the title upper case.  (text-transform: uppercase;)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to your stylesheet. Use the element inspector in Chrome or Firefox right clicking on the title selecting `inspect element`.

Somewhere among the style rules it'll say `text-transform: uppercase;`. Check which file and line and remove that from the stylesheet

Comment: Thank you.  I see that, I was just very hesitate to accept that the default installation would assume that there would not be anything case sensitive in the product name and I was hoping it was just something I had not set properly in the configuration.

Comment: nope, just some styling. Remove or overwrite it and you should be good :)

Comment: Thank you.  Sigh, you ever hear the term 'unintended consequences', it will be interesting to see where all the changes will manifest.  Have tended to be very cautious changing something as global as the global stylesheet!

Comment: use the .catalog-product-view class prefix to limit it to that page

Comment: I am actually just sitting here trying to decide if there is anywhere I want things all caps.  I must admit that it has not pleased me pretty much where ever I have seen it.

Comment: Setting a text element to all caps via CSS is exactly how it should be done. Be thankful you don't have some core modification doing something like `strtoupper($product->getName())` when products are saved!

Comment: Isn't it better to add these changes in a sub-theme?

Comment: Hm perhaps. Im more of a back ender. So thw ethics of frontending i cant really help you with

Comment: Most people recommend a child-theme, if the author of the theme decides to release an update and you made changes in the main files your changes will be overwritten. Creating a sub-theme is really easy and is considered best practice.

Comment: Have the answer to go with that, just a question from the day before. [Take a look](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60999/magento-multisite-using-same-theme-for-different-websites-but-with-the-different/61319#61319)