# How to make a landing page that "links" to different store views

Tags: multistore, landing-pages

I am relatively new to magento. I am trying to create a landing page that will have image links to the two different store views. I used this tip to set that up.
[How to setup multi stores with different themes for Magento CE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24367/how-to-setup-multi-stores-with-different-themes-for-magento-ce/24368#24368?newreg=ca66401534024a2395e7ce505825d5d6)

But there's a few problems.

1. I don't know if my approach is correct. I set up the stores and store views in magento, and then I created cms pages for each store and set them to the store view. Then, I created a cms landing page which I set to the default "home page", added the images and inserted the URL links. When the images are clicked it goes to the "page not found." I tried setting the store view for both pages to "all store views" and then the image links worked. But I don't know if this disconnects the page from the store and it's catalogue. Here's the homepage so you can see what I mean. http://tuckersfurniture.biz

2.I have set up theme variations for both the store views but I can't get them to show up. The file structure looks like this:

-app-design-frontend-hellowiredx-default
-app-design-frontend-hellowiredx-cashcarry
-app-design-frontend-hellowiredx-valleyfurniture

-skin-frontend-hellowiredx-default
-skin-frontend-hellowiredx-cashcarry
-skin-frontend-hellowiredx-valleyfurniture

The only difference between these are things like background color and logo. As far as I can tell, I have put the right names in the right fields in magento to call the different theme variants, so I don't think that is the problem. I think I somehow set up the pages or the stores wrong or the store is not properly linked to its respective page.

Like I said I'm relatively new at this so I appreciate any help I can get. I don't know much about PHP, so if that is part of the solution you might have to walk me through it.